# Vue route params with get request value

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Vue and Vue router. What is the best option to connect value from a get request, with parameter in Vue Router? I want this.id to be replaced by a value from the api request.

```
const User = {
 data() {
 return {
 loading: false,
 name: null
 }
},
 created() {
  this.fetchData()
  this.$router.push({ path: /user/${this.id} })
},
  watch: {
   $route: "fetchData"
},
  methods: {
   fetchData() {
    this.error = this.name = null
    this.loading = true
    fetch(`https://.../`, (err, post) => {
    if (this.$route.params.id !== id) return
    this.loading = false
    if (err) {
     this.error = err.toString()
       } else {
         this.post = post
        }
     })
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as you have added `props: true` in the router, you will receive `id` as a props
you can directly watch id instead of the whole `$route`.

```
props: ["id"],
created() {
  this.fetchData();
},
methods: {
  fetchData() {
    this.error = this.name = null
    this.loading = true
    fetch(`https://.../user/${this.id}`, (err, post) => {
      this.loading = false
      if (err) {
       this.error = err.toString()
      } else {
        this.post = post
      }
     })
   }
  }
},
watch: {
  id: function() {
    this.fetchData()
  }
}
```